# Cocompact (finite covolume) lattices in euclidean groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, euclidean-geometry

1) Is there a classification of cocompact ( or finite co-volume) lattices in Euclidean groups E(n)( motions of Euclidean space) ( especially in dimensions 2,3,4)?

2) Also what is (if any) the relation between, say, platonic solids and lattices in E(3)?

3) I would also appreciate any reference(s). Sorry for rather naive questions from non-expert in the area.

Comment: For the torsion-free case, Chapter 3 of Wolf: "Spaces of constant curvature" should be the ultimate reference. Note that any lattice has a torsion-free sublattice of finite index. In E(3) there are 10 torsion-free cocompact lattices (Hantzsche-Wendt 1935). I don't think there is a relation to platonic solids except that one of the lattices has the cube as a fundamental domain.

Comment: In $E(n)$, every lattice is cocompact. The main keyword is "Bieberbach's theorems". and another one is "crystallographic group". Then one has precise classification only in small dimension.

Comment: Platonic solids are related to lattices in (ie discrete subgroups of) $SO(3)$.

Comment: Charlap : "Bieberbach Groups and Flat Manifolds", is a reference on classification problems for Bieberbach groups